# How to eliminate results from an SQL query and get only certain non-repeated info?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's the deal:

[image: Tables relationship]

I have these tables, which are all for making a Steam-like application (downloading games, talking with friends, etc). My problem comes when I want to know which of my friends play each of my games (Say I play Minecraft, I would want to see which of my friends play Minecraft as well), and I'm struggling to form a query which will tell me that. I'd thought this could possibly be made with the help of the EXCEPT keywork, but I've tried to no avail.

Maybe this will help understand what I want to end up getting:

[image: Query results]

As you can see, I have *Crashex Legends* in common with **Migue**, and also *Crashex Legends* and *Overwatch* with **Test**. I want to see only one result per friend per common game, so that I would only see results 1, 8 and 9.

Comment: please do not post images post in text, and include data samples and desired results (in data).

Comment: Not sure how to post images as images, but I'll try

Comment: No post table structure in text, not a screen shot.  and what have you tried/done?

Comment: Didn't quite understand your question

Comment: Don't post images. You need to post text so anyone can copy and edit without wasting additional time.

Comment: This seems like a problematic db design. Are you using the names as the primary key? You should create surrogate keys to reduce data redundancy and wasted storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, try to use CTEs to help conceptualize it and break it into small pieces. I would create identity columns for your primary keys first. If you are not referencing using IDs then there is no benefit to using a relational database. But maybe something like this.
You don;t have to use CTEs but I think it helps take it step by step. The trick you are really looking for is in MyFriendsThatPlayMyGames_CTE. This is where you do a left join and then grab anything that is not null, meaning there was a match. Change to is null to get games your friends have that you don't etc.

```
with
MyFriends_CTE (me, friend)as(

    Select user1, user2
    from userFriends
    where user1 = @ME

    UNION

    Select user2, user1
    from userFriends
    where user2 = @Me
),

MyGames_CTE as (

 blah blah
),

MyFriendsGames_CTE as (

 select
from myfriends_cte
join games
),

MyFriendsThatPlayMyGames_CTE as(

select
from MyfriendsGames_CTE
left join myGames_CTE
on blah blah
where myGames_CTE.name is not null


)

select 
from MyFriendsThatPlayMyGames_CTE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. Didn't even know what CTE was. Had to sweat it a bit to understand what the hell was happening and what was missing in the 'blah blah' parts lol, but I think that ended up helping me. Thanks again, really.

Comment: You're welcome. CTEs examples are typically used to show recursive queries, so be prepared to get teased by other SQL people if you start doing this. You could used derived queries or sub quires to do the same thing, but doing it this way is the closest thing to clean coding you can do with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to JOIN to `UserGames` twice, instead of once with an OR.

JOIN once with `User1` and alias `UserGames` as UG1; 
Then JOIN again with `User2` and alias `UserGames` as UG2.

Then in your WHERE clause, find the rows where `UG1.Game = UG2.Game`

Answer (score 0):

Something like the code below should get you the data you're after.
As a best practice, don't use 'select *'; instead explicitly declare what columns you need returned. That being said, I don't get the idea you are into best practices as looking at your DB design is equivalent to hearing nails on a chalkboard; surrogate keys, third normal form, foreign keys constraints, etc.

```
SELECT 
   US.nickname, UG.game, MG.[user], MG.game
FROM UserFriends AS UF
JOIN Users AS US ON (UF.user1 = US.nickname OR UF.user2 = US.nickname) AND US.nickname <> 'Penny'
JOIN UserGames AS UG ON US.nickname = UG.[user]
JOIN UserGames AS MG ON UG.game = MG.game
WHERE 'Penny' IN (UF.user1, UF.user2)
AND MG.[user] = 'Penny'
```